# how to handle notification pending intent if app is not running in android

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

```
My Application 
StartUp Activity-> load tvguide Activity-> show program details activity

I've implemented simple app notification for my tv app guide activity, the user can set up a reminder for any tv program to notify before 5 min to start time when taps the notification he should see the detail program view.

StartUpActivity-> get the tv guide from server for next 24hrs 
TvguideActivity-> display the TV guide
programDetailsActivity-> display program details

If the application is running in background I don't want to show the start-Up Activity, as TV guide already have the data and I want to show the detailView

To handle the above scenario I created notification pendingIntent to TVGuide Activity 
Intent receiverIntent = new Intent(context, TvGuideActivity.class); this is all working as i want.
but my question is how can I handle the scenario when the app is not running (like user set up the reminder and terminate/force kill the app),
```

if I set the pending Intent to TvGuideActivity, it;s not loading the DetailView because there is no data. How to fix this two use cases?

Comment: You can user alarmmanager to set an alarm. It will automatically invokes the broadcastreceiver at that point of time. You can use your broadcastreceiver to push notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alarmmanager to fire a broadcastreceiver at that particular point of time. In the broadcastreceiver you can write your notification code.

```
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                     calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                     AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but my question is not about implementing alarm manager I already implemented that part, I just want to know how to handle the notification pending intent if the app is not running

Comment: While you are creating the pendingintent. you can bundle some data to it.

Comment: so which Activity you suggesting me to add to pending Intent?

Comment: you are showing the program details. where you are getting this program details data.

Comment: When creating the notification I set the program id to pending intent and retrieve this value  in TVGuideActivity and load the detail view

Comment: Startup Activity getting all the data right from the server. Its sending this data to tvguide activity. So, What i am trying to say is Load the same data when you are pushing the notification and bind this data to pending intent of tvguide activity.

Comment: yes that is what you have to do. You have to bind the program id in pending intent.

Comment: so you mean to set the Pending Intent always to "startup activity"?  and check the intent data and do accordingly, But this will show the splash screen if the app is already running in the background,

Comment: when you are opening the tvguideactivity you send data to tvguideactivity from startupactivity. When you are creating pending intent to tvguideactivity, get that data from server and bind it with pendingintent. In this case you know need to set pending intent to startupactivity. But you are loading the data from server when you are pushing notification.

Comment: Do you just want the notification to bring the app to the foreground in whatever state it was in before? If so, there are easy ways to do that